# python print only the names from text file

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, namedtuple

I can't get it to print only the names.
This is what I got so far
and here is the link for the malenames.txt:

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~kay/malenames.txt

```
from collections import namedtuple
FN = namedtuple('FN','name percent people rank')
FirstN = namedtuple('FirstN','FN')

def firstname()->str:
    '''returns a firstname from text file'''
    filein = open('malenames.txt','r')
    for str in filein:
        s = str.split('\t')
        print (s)
    FN1 = FN(s)
    F1 = FirstN(FN1)
    for name in F1:
        print(name)

firstname()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it:

```
with open("malenames.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
      print (line.split()[0])
```